# Java: A generic that returns a Long as a subtype of Number

Tags: java, type-conversion, numbers

I'm looking for a way to convert a long or Long to a type derived from Number:

```
public class IdentityConverter<ConvertedT extends Number> implements IBitcodeConverter<ConvertedT> {
    public IdentityConverter() {
    }

    @Override
    public ConvertedT FromBitcode(Long theBitcodeVal) {
        return new ConvertedT(theBitcodeVal.longValue());
    }

    @Override
    public Long ToBitcode(ConvertedT theConvertedVal) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return theConvertedVal.longValue();
    }

}
```

The Problem is the `FromBitcode` method. The current code doesn't work. How do I get a `ConvertedT` which is a `Number` from a `Long`? Surely there is a simple way to do that...

Comment: `Long` is declared as `extends Number`.  You do not need to convert it.

Comment: Duh. I'm certain I tried that. Eclipse complained about that, but now it seems to work. Strange.

Comment: @StephenC Unfortunately this results in a runtime error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new ConvertedT` won't work because `ConvertedT` is a type variable.

You need to provide something like a `Function<Long, ConvertedT>` (or a `LongFunction<ConvertedT>`) to the constructor of `IdentityConverter`, in order to be able to construct the right kind of thing.

```
public class IdentityConverter<ConvertedT extends Number> implements IBitcodeConverter<ConvertedT> {
    private final Function<Long, ConvertedT> fn;

    public IdentityConverter(Function<Long, ConvertedT> fn) {
      this.fn = fn;
    }

    @Override
    public ConvertedT FromBitcode(Long theBitcodeVal) {
        return fn.apply(theBitcodeVal);
    }

    // ...
}
```